# Mongodb: What is the best way to search multiple collections for the same field in one query

Tags: mongodb

I inherited a bunch of collections and each of them have fields in common.
Is there a way to query the "EMAIL" field in collection A and Collection B ....or Am I stuck with iterating through the collections programmatically ?

> db.colA.find({"EMAIL":"joe@doe.com"})

**Collection A :** 
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58197fc91b69ba68721d4148"), "UUID" : "0b6827f2-9384-11e0-8f4a-b8ac6f949be6", "EMAIL" : "JOHNDOE@YAHEE.COM", "FNAME" : "JOHN", "LNAME" : "DOE"}

**Collection B:** 
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4ed234423654fea654a654f2"), "SOURCE" : "65488451522", "EMAIL" : "JOHNDOE@YAHEE.COM", "FN" : "JOHN", "DOB":"05/13/1967"}

Expected behavior: the search query would returned both records.

Well, why not query Col A and Col B .. I have 17 collections in the DB, one query would be great.

Comment: please provide sample doc from your collections A and B and the expected output. I'm not sure to understand what you want to achieve

Answer (score 1):

You can use the aggregation lookup to achieve this:

```
db.colA.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: "colB",
          localField: "EMAIL",
          foreignField: "EMAIL",
          as: "connected_query"
        }
   }
])
```

You will then have a field called connected_query in your results that refer to colB results that have the same email as colA.

Comment: how would you use this in a case where you have over 17 collections ? It really is about finding a document that contains that one field (Email in this case), the document can be in any or multiple collections out of the 17.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in a single query with your current collections. 
You may be able to achieve this with [DBRefs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/#dbref-explanation), but it will soon be deprecated (if not already), so don't use it unless it's absolutely necessary.

Even if running the same query on 17 distincts collections is not very elegant, I guess this is still the best option

Comment: I was afraid of that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about joins, $lookup has been enabled in mongo latest version. Java doc: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Comment: The collections are independent one another. They just happen to have fields (Like email and phone for instance) in common. When I need to look for the rest of the information, I m not sure which collection the record I am looking for is. So I have to query every collection in the database. In NOde or PHP I can just loop into it, I was wondering if there is an option in the find() - or other command - that will allow to specify which collection to use for the query.

Comment: My knowledge on mongodb may be limited, but I don't think you can achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do that. You're stuck to having to do that programmatically. Although MongoDB has embedded documents and an 'entity' might be scatted in many collections, there should be one collection which represents the complete entity

For example, you might have a UserProfile collection but snippets of user profile might be embedded in other collections. In that case when you need the complete user's profile, you query it straight from UserProfile collection.